# Is there any disease in adult human, other-than cancer, which-is resulted from mutation?

Tags: biochemistry, cell-biology, cancer, pathology, mutations

On all environmental articles I read about 3 impacts of mutagens (say Cigarette/ Naphthalene/ EtBr/ Colchicine/ ionizing radiation/ whatever )...

**1**. direct effect on tissues, other than mutation, such-as burns, choke, cirrhosis of liver, Lesion in lungs etc. (**no direct relation with mutation**)

**2**. Mutation affecting development of organs and intelligence, in youngs; and hidden mutation not affecting adults but showing expression (**birth-defects**) in **future progeny**.

and

**3**. **Tumor and Cancer.**

**Now, my question is,** if an adult become exposed to some mutagen; the only visible effect of mutation (**not** about burns etc, talking about genetic-mutation) ... **on that affected-individual**; whether **cancer is the only-possible disease**? or it is possible to occur **some-other sort of genetic disease**  (**not** about future **but only to that particular affected-one**)

---

**anything else should happen** ... say exact opposite thing... uncontrolled apoptosis that gradually kills whole affected person (for say).

or for say due to a genetic-damage a person became unable to perform cell-division, so no wound healing. If once part of body become cut, and it remain open forever, never seals. (I never heard or read anywhere).

**instead of cell-death**, they could perform some-**other malfunctions**, too. Like **turning-off certain normal function**, say stopped **transport** of certain molecule, or say stopped a function like **color-vision**, or start to **secrete / accumulate some metabolites** same-way as inborn error of metabolism?

But could anything such happen other-than cancer?

Comment: Are you asking about radiation poisoning?

Comment: @James Any mutagen. Radiation, Cigarettes, Naphthalene, EtBr, Colchicine, whatever

Comment: I cant recall anything else than cancer , that could affect an adult directly. That is quite bizarre. A malfunctuning gene should give rise to many-other problem... why cancer only???????

Comment: Cancer is a wide collection of different diseases with a huge variety of symptoms and physiological impacts. Another DNA damage based disease is [acute radiation poisoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acute_radiation_syndrome). I also have a feeling that sometimes DNA damage can lead to sclerosis... I'd have to look it up.

Comment: Hmm but basic phenomenon of cancer is uncontroled growth and proliferation of calls with some destructive activities without any apoptosis. But anything else could happen ... say exact opposite thing... uncontrolled apoptosis , but I never heard about that.

Comment: or , for say due to a genetic-damage a person became unable to perform cell-division, so no wound healing. I never heard or read anywhere.

Comment: Or for say after accidental consuming a poison, a person became color-blind due to DNA malfunction... could happen?

Comment: Once DNA is damaged the cell will be destroyed, it cannot replicate and the disease won't emerge. Healthy cells replace them. However in cancer the damaged cells are not killed because those were the mechanisms that were damaged; cancer will proliferate. This won't happen in cells that are damaged in other ways but still retain cell cycle control. With radiation sickness, DNA damage causes a lot of *immediate* symptoms because so many cells are damaged too badly to replicate and will be destroyed.

Comment: Let's use your examples. Say a cell gained the trait of uncontrolled apoptosis. What would happen? It would die and the damage is not passed on. If a cell becomes unable to divide, it will not be able to replicate and no disease will occur. You would need to instantly damage all the DNA of cells in the body in a very specific way to see disease states like that emerge. In a manner of speaking, this is what viruses aim to do - change host cell DNA in a specific way to do their bidding.

Comment: But instead of die, they could perform some-other malfunctions, too. Like turning-off certain normal function, say stopped transport of certain molecule, or say stopped a function like color-vision, or  start to secrete / accumulate some metabolites same-way as inborn error of metabolism?

Comment: If that sort of damage occurs, the cell cycle control mechanisms will target the cell for destruction, and the disease trait will not be passed onto another cell.

Comment: One answer from one of my teachers: [Xeroderma pigmentosum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xeroderma_pigmentosum).

Comment: I thought we were discussing somatic mutation diseases, not inherited mutations that cause disease. Xeroderma pigmentosum for example can be carried with relatively little effect because other alleles can pick up the slack of the defective allele. The disease only appears when a child inherits two defective copies of the gene.

Comment: In your question however, you ask about mutations that cause disease because of mutation agents such as tobacco radiation etc, not inherited defective genes.

Comment: @James Yes. You are on exact correct point. Not on other generation but the same individual organism who is taking the exposure such as consuming the cigarette smoke etc.

Comment: A previous comment mentioned radiation poisoning. An interesting thing to note is that most cells that suddenly develop a large number of mutations (e.g. through mutagen exposure) will automatically undergo apoptosis (an evolved sacrifice-self-to-save-the-body mechanism). If too many cells undergo apoptosis at once because of this (as can happen after a large dose of radiation), that can actually severly sicken or kill the person. Thus a person dies or is sickened from their body's reaction to numerous mutations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before answering your question, an important note. Not all neoplastic growth is malignant. A mutation may result in a benign growth, which is an outcome different from cancer. Not all of these change to cancers. Moreover, almost all genetic diseases may arise *de novo* as a germline mutation, and this mutation may be caused due to the environmental mutagen, and hence will be a non-neoplastic outcome of environmental mutation. The list of such genetic diseases is impossible to replicate here.

Assuming you are asking non-malignant diseases involving somatic (acquired) mutation as a pathogenetic event, here's a subset.

Some diseases with **proven somatic mutation** are:

Neurofibromatosis 1 & 2
McCune-Albright
Paroxysmal Nocturnal Hemoglobinuria
Incontinentia Pigmenti

For more details, have a look at this paper here.
[Erickson RP. Somatic gene mutation and human disease other than cancer. Mutation Research/Reviews in Mutation Research. 2003 Mar 31;543(2):125-36.](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1383574203000103)